# How can I display a Facebook "likebox" in my website? 

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

How can I display a Facebook "likebox" in my website?

Answer (score 2):

You can go make the button [right here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Or you can get the "likes" of a page via JSON just by using their [Graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/225397695229/) (it's in the returned data here)

Answer (score 0):

Javaamtho may be referring to the like box for facebook pages

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

and here's  a nifty tool to customize it a bit

http://prettylikebox.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPAGE_NAME&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true&amp;" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:590px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"><a href="YOUR_URL" class="fbook">klj</a></iframe>
```